# Database or faster way to work with database

Tags: sql, json, web, nosql

SQL is one of the most powerful and most currently used languages​​, but for purposes of curiosity and learning would test new technologies and want to know what are the fastest.

I text talking about NoSQL (json) and also about "plain text" file (. Txt or. Dat or. INI) with information from publications, settings, and the like.

What is the fastest processing, taking for example the Wordpress CMS is a very famous and one of the largest in the world, it uses SQL, say we make a request of 50 posts from the database, using the default template, all standardized compared with a requisition 50 posts from the same hierarchy but in file. txt or json file, which technology and fashion that renders faster?

Comment: Speed always depends on a specific scenario. You can't fairly rank different database technologies by speed. In Scenario A under circumstances B on hardware C, system 1 might be faster than system 2, but in scenario D under circumstanced E on hardware F it could look completely different.

Comment: I think it's a generic question. Because the choice depends on the scenario. For example if you want save only 3 string is obsolete use a database like mysql, sqlserver or db no sql; it's better use flat file or embedded database(like sqlite). But if you want save a large amount of data you must use database like mysql or mongodb(if you want use no sql db).

Comment: Not only that, but it's also a question of what kind of queries the database can handle. SQL handles all kinds of queries, NoSQL can't (easily) handle joins, and with flat text files you can't even talk about queries. Converting full Wordpress functionality to flat files would be a) stupid and b) very slow, but showing just blog posts from flat text files would probably be faster, etc. etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you will work with storage only in read or write, json or text file will be more faster than mysql, otherwise if you want to process complex data, mysql is faster.

If you want to work with less overhead, try to use SQLite database or similar

NoSQL databases like Redis, MongoDB is faster than MySql, but for using it, you must have personal hosting with root access

Comment: "NoSQL databases like Redis, MongoDB is faster than MySql" -> That's a gross overgeneralization. They are faster at some use-cases, but much slower in other. Take JOINs, for example. With MongoDB you can't perform them on the database and have to do them on the application layer by executing sequential queries, which is much slower than in a relational database.

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't have numbers to prove my guess, I think that any database will always be faster than a text file, just consider its indexing capabilities.

If instead you want to compare different databases, then, as others already said, it's a matter of the specific domain / problem you're working on and the structure you gave to the specific database schema.